# Make combo box record as table field name , MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, subform, ms-access-forms

I have combo box in form, i want to have it's drop down value to be Table fields name.Table name is tblCap, and the field are Year1,Year2 and Year3.I want that in the Combo box to have dropdown list as Year1,Year2,Year3 and when that year is selected it should display related field in subform.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update after comments.

Once the `RowSource` has been set-up as per @Gustav answer, in order to hide/unhide the TextBox controls according to the value of ComboBox you need to set their `Visible` property to `True/False`.

On the Events tab set the `AfterUpdate` of your ComboBox control to `[Event Procedure]` and on the code behind file set the following:

```
Private Sub YourComboControlName_AfterUpdate()
    With Me
        Select Case .YourComboBoxName.Value
            Case "Year1":
                With .YourSubformName.Form
                    .Your2000TextBoxControlName.ColumnHidden = false 
                    .Your2001TextBoxControlName.ColumnHidden = true
                    .Your2002TextBoxControlName.ColumnHidden = true 
                End With

            Case "Year2":
                With .YourSubformName.Form
                    .Your2000TextBoxControlName.ColumnHidden = true
                    .Your2001TextBoxControlName.ColumnHidden = false
                    .Your2002TextBoxControlName.ColumnHidden = true 
                End With

            Case "Year3":
                With .YourSubformName.Form
                    .Your2000TextBoxControlName.ColumnHidden = true 
                    .Your2001TextBoxControlName.ColumnHidden = true 
                    .Your2002TextBoxControlName.ColumnHidden= false 
                End With
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You have me confused. There's no such thing as crosstab table. A query perhaps?

Comment: 2000,2001 and 2002 are field names. Are you looking to display the field names in the combobox?

Comment: Kostas,hi , can you kindly let me know how to relate fields with combo box , like in combo box i added value , now when that value is selected it should display that column in subform? really thankful for your help.

Comment: If I understood correctly, on the `Combo_AfterUpdate()` set the `ControlSource` of your control in subform to the value of the Combobox e.g. `Me.YourSubformName.Form.YourYearControlName.ControlSource = Me.YourComboControlName.Value`.

Comment: See update. The combobox values are not 2000,2001,2002 but Year1, Year2, Year3.

Comment: On the Case statements, you just need to put the values of the combobox.

Comment: What are the values of your combobox? When you click the control arrow, which values are being displayed on the drop-down?

Comment: The code is correct. Is the subform name correct? Click on it once to select it and then on the 'Other' tab in properties check the Name.

Comment: What is the format of your combobox control? You can check this on the Format tab after selecting the combobox.

Comment: Try this as well, change `cboYear_AfterUpdate` to `cboYear_Change`

Comment: are the textbox controls enabled?

Comment: Can you check the Events tab of the combobox? There should be an `[Event Procedure]` on the On Change.

Comment: On the Visual Basic Editor, under Debug select the first option 'Compile xxx' to see if you get any errors.

Comment: Dont really know, I've tried every possible scenario. You need to investigate further. Set a breakpoint to the sub and go line by line by pressing F8 to see what it does.

Comment: i make a new form also , in main form visible property but not in subform , i dont know is this a default behavior or what it is .

Comment: i go line by line and an error came ,"you can't hide control that have focus" , do you know anything about it?

Comment: Guys, i found the solution :) instead of Visible we have to use ColumHidden property as The visible property works on
controls, not the datasheet view. we would need to set the column's hidden
attribute and then it work.

Comment: Thank you again everyone for help.

Comment: hello , can you let me know how to make this code work in two combo box , for each of them they work fine separately but when i combine them one work and the other doesn't, can you help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

This is much simpler than you may imagine:

1. Open the Property sheet of the combobox, tab *Data*
2. Set *RowSourceType*: Value List
3. Set *RowSource*: "Year1";"Year2";"Year3"

To display the selected value (field name) in a subform, use this expression:

```
=[Parent]![NameOfYourCombobox]
```

To display, in a textbox on the main form, the value of the selected field name of the subform:

```
=[NameOfYourSubformControl].[Form]([NameOfYourCombobox])
```

or (?) on the subform:

```
=[Parent]([Parent]![NameOfYourCombobox])
```

Comment: thank you but then after that how i will display that field like how the link will be? When from combo box Year1 is click it should display that field (Year1)  in below subform, how that will work?

Comment: Use the _AfterUpdate_ event as @Kostas already has showed. Or a similar method.

Comment: I've added that expression to my answer.

Comment: The expression is the _ControlSource_ for your TextBox that is supposed to display the value. No code needed.

Comment: how it will work for all textbox ? when 2000 will be click in combo box , it should display in subform field 2000, when 2001 is click how it will be link to 2001 to unhide it as i have written in values in combo box.

Comment: You wrote: "it should display related field in subform." It sounds as you would have to completely rephrase your question.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't precise enough , display related field like to show/unhide field when it is selected in combo box like when 2000 is selected in combo box it should display field 2000 only , when 2001 is selected should unhide that and so.

Comment: I can't follow. First you mention "display related field in subform", then "how it will work for all textbox", and now you wish " to show/unhide field".

Comment: display related field mean to show field that is related with that combo box value , as i said by clicking on 2000 it should display field 2000. For textbox i said because the field in subform are text box in design view and when go to form view it's a datasheet, so for that reason i said how it will work for textbox. For these three things the main point is to show related fields or to unhide/make visible the field that link with that value.and again Sorry if i didn't explain well.